# Jenkins: dealing with many build configurations

Tags: deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration

The shop I work for is using jenkins for continuous integration and its promoted builds plugin to deploy build artifacts.  However, we're having trouble managing this set up as the number of configurations grows.  So my question is:

**How can I set up a handy CI system from which I can deploy various artifacts in various configurations without manually scripting every possible combination?**

Some more details:

Let's say I have build configurations (i.e. branches) `A`, `B` and `C`.  There are three deployment  targets `I`, `J` and `K` (say for various clients or consumers).  Finally, each deployed instance has various services `X`, `Y` and `Z`  (e.g. web-site, background tasks and data-service).  The various services are usually promoted together; but sometimes, particularly to get hotfixes out, they're not.

Currently, we have promotions for each of these combinations.  So to install a typical build I'd need to run promotions `J/X`, `J/Y` and `J/Z` on config `C`.  The number of services is unfortunately rising, and getting all those configurations in jenkins without making any error, and furthermore ensure that none of the components are forgotten or mixed up when deployment comes around is getting tricky.  And of course, there are more than three build configs and more than three targets, so it's all getting out of hand.

Some options that don't quite work:

- Parametrized promotions to disable various components.  Jenkins allows parametrized promotions, but the values are fixed the first time you promote.  I could remove a degree of freedom by just promoting `J` and setting some parameters, but if a later version breaks, I can't rollback only the component that broke, I need to rollback the entire deployment.
- Dependant, parametrized builds.  Jenkins doesn't seem to support parameters to choose which build to depend on, and if you manually code the options then of course the "run" selection parameter can't work.

What I'd really want:

- After a build is manually accepted as ready for deployment, it should be marked as such including an argument for which target and arguments for which components.
- the installation history is logged per-component per-target, *not* (only) per-build.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some plugins to help, but you also may be approaching the point where looking at commercial tools is appropriate. I work for a build/deploy vendor ([Urbancode](http://Urbancode.com)) so by all means take this with a giant grain of salt.

We generally see people have different build types (or branches) for a single project and group those as a single 'project' with multiple 'build workflows' using the same basic configuration with some per workflow parameterization. Really simple reuse of process.

> The number of services is unfortunately rising, and getting all those configurations in jenkins without making any error, and furthermore ensure that none of the components are forgotten or mixed up when deployment comes around is getting tricky. And of course, there are more than three build configs and more than three targets, so it's all getting out of hand.

If the challenge here is that you have multiple web services and promotions (especially to production) involve pushing lots of stuff, at specific versions, in a coordinated manner you're hitting the standard use case for our [application release automation tool](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/deploy/), uDeploy. It's conveniently integrated with Jenkins. It also has really nice tracking of what version of what went to what deployment target, and who ran that process.

Comment: grain of salt applied; but thanks! I'll definitely look at uDeploy.